# Find sum across different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have six workbooks, all identical. Every workbook has some value in A2, B2, C2 cells of the second sheet of the workbook. I want a consolidated Excel sheet which would produce the sum of A2s,B2s,C2s of sheet2 of all workbooks. I put all the six workbooks in a newfolder and created a new workbook and used the following code,

```
Sub SumWB()
  Dim Arr(2) As Long, MyWB As Workbook, fStr As String
  Const Folder = "C:\Users\satsobek\Downloads\New folder\"
  fStr = Dir(Folder)
  While (file <> "")
    Set MyWB = Workbooks.Open(Folder & fStr, , True)
    Arr(0) = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(2).Range("A2").Value
    Arr(1) = Arr(1) + MyWB.Sheets(2).Range("B2").Value
    Arr(2) = Arr(2) + MyWB.Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value
    MyWB.Close
    file = Dir
  Wend
  Debug.Print Arr(0) & " - " & Arr(1) & " - " & Arr(2)
End Sub
```

and wanted to initially check whether the output produces the sum. But I am getting only

```
0-0-0
```

as output.

Can anybody help me in debugging the code to find the sum of A2s,B2s and C2s of sheet2 across various workbooks?

Comment: Hm, this works for me.  Perhaps silly question, but are you sure you have a `Sheets(2)`? (Note that `Sheets(2)` isn't necessarily the same as `Sheets("Sheet2")`.

Comment: That is something which I tried changing. What do we do to navigate to the second sheet?

Comment: Or is there a way we can pass the sheet name? or second sheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne - I am surprised it worked for you *as written*. There is a difference in variable declaration that causes the `While` loop to exit right away because the variable `file` is empty.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I must confess, I ran the `Arr()` parts, skipping the loop where it looks for a file. I was just checking first if his `Arr()` worked - it did, so then I was drawn to thinking it's something with his file declarations.  And now I see you're all over it, so nice work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you define the file to search for.

You set `fStr = Dir(Folder)` Then you say `While (file <> "")` Since `file` is not set initially, the `While Loop` will exit right away (because `file` does not ever get set until the first loop - which never happens).

Change all references of `fStr` to `file` and it will work.

```
Sub SumWB()
  Dim Arr(2) As Long, MyWB As Workbook, fStr As String
  Const Folder = "C:\Users\satsobek\Downloads\New folder\"
  file = Dir(Folder)
  While (file <> "")

    If file <> "consol.xlsx" Then 
       Set MyWB = Workbooks.Open(Folder & file, , True)
       Arr(0) = Arr(0) + MyWB.Sheets(2).Range("A2").Value
       Arr(1) = Arr(1) + MyWB.Sheets(2).Range("B2").Value
       Arr(2) = Arr(2) + MyWB.Sheets(2).Range("C2").Value
       MyWB.Close
    End If
    file = Dir
  Wend
  Debug.Print Arr(0) & " - " & Arr(1) & " - " & Arr(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: There's a second `fstr` to change.  `Set MyWB = Workbooks.Open(Folder & fStr, , True)`

Comment: When I use this piece of code, I am getting the following error,

Run time error '1004':

C:\Users\satsobek\Downloads\New folder\ path cannot be found. Check the spelling of the file name,and verify that the file location is correct

Comment: okay, but it still exits the loop on the very first pass since `file` is empty.

Comment: When I use the modified code, After I run the macro, I am getting, "consol.xlsx is already open. Reopening will cause any changes you made  to be discarded. Do you want to open the consol.xlsx" 

and I gave yes. Then the excel file restarts and the entire piece of macros disappears.

and also there is no output at all in that file. This is the problem I was facing while using some other code also. Not sure what mistake I am doing.

Comment: @SilentObserver - is the main workbook where you are doing the consolidation in the folder as well? and is the consolidation workbook called `"consol.xlsx"`

Comment: Yeah it is also saved in the same folder and I have named it consol.xlsx

Comment: The problem is once I run the macro, the file restarts and the macro which I used earlier disappears.

Comment: since you have `consol.xlsx` open already and running the macro from that, tell the macro to ignore that file when it comes to, because you cannot re-open a file that is already open. see my edited code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Aaahhhhh!! this is the problem which has been driving me crazy for some time. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ScottHoltzman One last help. Can we store these values to Some cells in the consol worksheet? May be A2,B2,C2 of this worksheet?

Comment: of course you can - but you can figure that one out right? `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2") = Arr(0)` ...  Please mark as answered if this solves your original question as written.